# How to use rlang pronouns without generating errors - .data

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

```
  original_data <- data.frame(
    V1 = 1:5,
    V2 = 6:10,
    V3 = 11:15
  )
```

Hi, I am writing a package in R that passes all of the checks in `devtools::check()`, so that I need to use the `.data` pronoun when using `tidyverse` functions.

Without using it, everything works out.:

```
  separated_data <- original_data %>%
    dplyr::mutate(id_0 = dplyr::row_number()) %>%
    dplyr::select(V1, V2)
```

However, I get the following error when using it:

```
  separated_data <- original_data %>%
    dplyr::mutate(id_0 = dplyr::row_number(.data)) %>%
    dplyr::select(.data$V1, .data$V2)

 Problem with `mutate()` input `id_0`.
x Can't take the `names()` of the `.data` pronoun
i Input `id_0` is `dplyr::row_number(.data)`.
```

Here is my session info:

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] magrittr_2.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fansi_0.4.1       assertthat_0.2.1  crayon_1.3.4      dplyr_1.0.2       R6_2.5.0         
 [6] lifecycle_0.2.0   pillar_1.4.7      cli_2.2.0         rlang_0.4.9       rstudioapi_0.13  
[11] vctrs_0.3.5       generics_0.1.0    ellipsis_0.3.1    tools_4.0.3       glue_1.4.2       
[16] purrr_0.3.4       compiler_4.0.3    pkgconfig_2.0.3   tidyselect_1.1.0  tibble_3.0.4.9000
```

I have found similar issues https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-is-not-empty/71089/5 that seemed related to an older version of package `tibble`. But even if I download a more recent development version I still get the problem.

When using the real function inside the package, I get

```
Can't convert a `rlang_fake_data_pronoun` object to function
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Doesn't `row_number` usually need a vector of values by which to rank? Without any values, this is equivalent to `dplyr::mutate(id_0 = 1:dplyr::n())` and this shouldn't produce any issues with `R CMD check`. If you do create row numbers based on values in a specific column `x`, the `R CMD check`-safe command would be `dplyr::mutate(id_0 = dplyr::row_number(.data$x))`.

Comment: If it `row_number()` works without a parameter in the first code, then you don't need to add `.data`. `original_data %>% dplyr::mutate(id_0 = dplyr::row_number()) %>% dplyr::select(.data$V1, .data$V2)` should work and pass the package checks.

Comment: thank you! I guess it only worked after I had done other change too, that being removing the pronoun from ```dplyr::ungroup(.data)```

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito I'm not entirely sure I follow your last comment. If you don't create row numbers based on values in some other column, I'd recommend using `id_0 = 1:dplyr::n()` (or `id_0 = seq_len(dplyr::n())`) instead of `id_0 = 1:dplyr::row_number()` (the latter defaults to the former for missing `x`). Not sure what you're trying to do with `dplyr::ungroup(.data)` but this will give an error. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I got confused in the use of  ````.data````. I use ````ungroup```` in the original function. On my mind, I had to insert ````.data```` also in all places that ````%>%```` would enable omitting the first argument, such as ````ungroup````